# runtime parameters in stage level for azuredevops pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are using multistage pipeline in azuredevops server and as we have a number of stages for deployments and integrations test. As its multistage pipeline, we have given the developers the capability to re-run the sages with their needs. By using the VG , the developers can make necessary changes to the pipeline by changing Variable values in the VG and rerunning. But each time they have to switch the window to VG to make necessary change. So we are looking for a way. so that the developers can input parameters(runtime parameters) during each stages re-running. Is it possible to achieve in Azuredevops Pipelines?

Comment: azure devops pipeline parameters will help. and in azure devops runtime using variables, and compile-time using parameters.

Comment: Sorry.. not clear about this suggestion

Comment: @Vowneee The parameters can only set value when running a new Pipeline. Based on your requirement, you need to set the value when re-running the stage. It should not meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to achieve in Azuredevops Pipelines?

I am afraid that there is no such option can update the variables or parameters value when re-running the Pipeline stage.

For the [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) in YAML Pipeline, the value of the parameter needs to be set when running a new Pipeline run.

When you re-run the stage, it will keep using the origin value of the parameter.

It doesn't support updating the value when running Pipeline stage.

For the variables in Variable Group, when we re-run the stage, it also does not provide the option to update the value of the variable at runtime.

[image]

We need to go to the Variable Group page to update the value and re-run the pipeline stage.

If there are fewer variables to update, you can also consider using a script to run Rest API to update the variables value of the variable Group.

```
$VariableGroupId = "variablegroupid"
$NewValue = "newvalue"
$VariableName = "variablename"
Write-Host "NewValue : $NewValue"
$url ="https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{Projectname}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/$($VariableGroupId)?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$token = "PAT"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers  @{Authorization = "Basic $token"}
$definition.variables.$VariableName.value = $NewValue
$definitionJson = $definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -ContentType "application/json"  -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($definitionJson))
```

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.